# Graphic novel with pink and white cover, printed in black and white, about a female lead living in a space station, joining a military group/the army

Tags: story-identification, comics, space

I read a graphic novel whilst working in a library that featured a female lead character, that lives on a space station of some kind that, after humans no longer live on Earth.

There was an older woman in it as well as her family member or guardian who I think was killed by some kind of gang.

Also there may have been either gang warfare or some kind or civil war that was breaking out on the space station, that led her to leave and join some kind or army or military group, where she was sent to fight on a planet that featured a void or portal that took the soldiers into the planet where time moved at a different rate, so a few hours or minutes at the base would mean a tour of several years had passed on the planet.

I read it in around 2010, but it may have come out before then. The cover was pink and white and the drawings were black and white.

Comment: What style of art? Is it cartoony? Realistic? Manga-like?

Comment: Kinda reminded me of tank girl type illustrations, but not quite as outlandish. Definitely cartoon style.

Comment: Can I get you to go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if any of that prompts more details?

Comment: The link hasn't offered me any further assistance. I have recalled all detail that I can remember in my original question. I don't know the title of the book or the author.

Comment: Were the characters caucasian? Dark-skinned? Asian? European? Hairstyles? What sort of weaponry was in use by the gang members or soldiers?

Comment: Sorry,  I am new to this kind of forum, so I don't really understand the point of editing my original question Jenayah. When I originally wrote the question out I had spaced as you corrected, but when it posted it had been changed. Does changing my choice of words increase the likelihood of a helpful answer?

Comment: A mixture or ethnicities, cant recall details on weapons other than maybe metal poles. Soldiers used pulse pistols or laser weapon of some kind I think. But again, I cant recall now.

Comment: Hey there! For info, you can use `@username` (for instance @FuzzyBoots) so that specific users get notified you replied to their comments. As for the spacing out, the formatting here can be a bit tricky, you need two line breaks to space out paragraphs. As for the title edit, yes, I took the liberty of including more info so that people who might only read the title could think "hey, I know that". But if you disagree with anything I edited, you can [edit] your question the way you want. Hope all this info helps :)

Comment: No that's fine, I was a bit irked that it had been changed when I posted it. Thank you for your help @Jenayah :)

Answer (score 7):

I think this is **[Halo Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Halo_Jones)** by Alan Moore and Ian Gibson, originally serialised in *2000 AD* from 1984 and later collected in three volumes. There are some differences, such as her not living on a space station, but in "The Hoop"m, which is moored in the Atlantic Ocean off the East coast of America. Nor is there any time dilation (see below), but the rest of the details fit, including the pink cover (of Book Two) and B&W interior art.

In the first book, we follow 18-year-old Halo Jones over one day, on her violent, though also partly comical misadventures on a shopping trip. Finally returning to her apartment, Halo finds her flatmate and best friend Brinna murdered, then discovers another good friend has become a "Different Drummer" (a youth cult perpetually numbed by the implant-generated beat of a drum in their ears). She decides to leave Earth, never to return.

 In the second book, Halo has become a stewardess on a year-long space cruise.

In the last book, ten years have elapsed and Halo has become a soldier serving in a Vietnam-style guerilla war and is courted by a famous, fearsome-looking general, Luiz Cannibal. I don't remember any time dilation (you may be mixing it up with Joe Haldeman's *The Forever War*), but the soldiers are forced to wear special suits to survive in an environment of extreme gravity, which they enter through a portal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Halo Jones sounds right. In Book Three the gravity on the planet that they are fighting on is so great that time is slowed down - hence, in part, why they were the large encounter suits.

Comment: Oh My Goodness !!! That is it !!! I think the one I read was an omnibus edition as it was just one book...but thank you so much @Klaus Æ. Mogensen this has driven me mad for years... Thank you again :D

Comment: @GemmaRPTheonlyoneJanes And for a last task on this Q&A, can you click the check mark on the left side of the answer. That will award points to Klaus. Thank you!